# Location is no longer logging after closing the project

Tags: ios, swift

I created a view and added Mapkit, then went and wrote my code to fetch the users location and display it on the map. The first time it seemed to work, after closing Xcode and opening the project (via terminal "open project name")it seemed to stop showing the location, I am not sure if this is a bug or not. I tried different simulators, for the iPhone 8 plus, I get the following error

`2018-10-24 21:04:44.112488-0400 Jama3aV2[55977:5431299] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7fbe67d00a00] get output frames failed, state 8196
2018-10-24 21:04:44.112802-0400 Jama3aV2[55977:5431299] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x7fbe67d00a00] get output frames failed, state 8196
2018-10-24 21:04:44.116124-0400 Jama3aV2[55977:5431299] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2018-10-24 21:04:44.116306-0400 Jama3aV2[55977:5431299] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2018-10-24 21:04:44.404369-0400 Jama3aV2[55977:5431298] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C6.1:2][0x7fbe67f0e490] get output frames failed, state 8196
2018-10-24 21:04:44.404509-0400 Jama3aV2[55977:5431298] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C6.1:2][0x7fbe67f0e490] get output frames failed, state 8196
2018-10-24 21:04:44.404894-0400 Jama3aV2[55977:5431298] TIC Read Status [6:0x0]: 1:57
2018-10-24 21:04:44.405132-0400 Jama3aV2[55977:5431298] TIC Read Status [6:0x0]: 1:57
2018-10-24 21:04:44.626215-0400 Jama3aV2[55977:5431297] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C8.1:2][0x7fbe67d07270] get output frames failed, state 8196
2018-10-24 21:04:44.626364-0400 Jama3aV2[55977:5431297] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C8.1:2][0x7fbe67d07270] get output frames failed, state 8196
2018-10-24 21:04:44.626818-0400 Jama3aV2[55977:5431297] TIC Read Status [8:0x0]: 1:57
2018-10-24 21:04:44.626962-0400 Jama3aV2[55977:5431297] TIC Read Status [8:0x0]: 1:57`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I have added the "privacy:location When In Use Description" in my info.plist . Here is my code:

``import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var addressTextView: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let regionInMeters: Double = 1000

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    checkLocationServices()


}


func setupLocationManager(){
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
}


func checkLocationServices() {
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        setupLocationManager()
        checkLocationAuthorization()
    } else {


    }
}

func centerViewLocationServices() {
    if let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate {
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: location, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters , longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}

func checkLocationAuthorization() {
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        centerViewLocationServices()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        break
    case .denied:
        break
    case .notDetermined:
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        break
    case .restricted:
        break
    case .authorizedAlways:
        break

    }
}
```

}

extension MapViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.last else { return }
    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion.init(center: center, latitudinalMeters: regionInMeters, longitudinalMeters: regionInMeters)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    checkLocationAuthorization()
}
```

}
``

I have followed the following youtube tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPpaAy73nJc&lc=z22phjvoivbcuxs4104t1aokgvm4f0nlq11ws3nrrojgbk0h00410.1540259497069676

Comment: sorry about the layout of the question, I hope its not too ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use print to print out the user's locations latitude and longitude if you want to always see it in console

In locationManager do this :

print(location.coordinate.latitude)
print(location.coordinate.longitude)

Oh yeah, NEVER use location with simulators, they suck, use a proper phone

Comment: Oh okay, I was hoping that I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Tried the simulators on both iOS and Android for location and they are terrible.However the phones work very well.